# How do I change the value and save it to a file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm making a small admin panel
There is a file for example **settings.ini**
with data:

```
siteName=Site name
sideDesc= Site Description
```

How do I get this data to the admin panel and change the value and after that, when saving, so that the data changes in this file

I know how to do it in the database, but I don't understand how to do it with a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in fs (File System) module in Node.js to read from and write to files. I left a basic example of how you might do this.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    // Read the file
    fs.readFile('settings.ini', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
    
      // Parse the data (assuming it's in the format "key=value")
      const settings = {};
      data.split('\n').forEach(line => {
        const [key, value] = line.split('=');
        settings[key] = value;
      });
    
      // Now `settings` is an object with the data from the file
      // You can modify it as needed, for example:
      settings.siteName = 'New site name';
    
      // Then you can write it back to the file
      const newData = Object.entries(settings).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`).join('\n');
      fs.writeFile('settings.ini', newData, 'utf8', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
    
        console.log('File has been updated');
      });
    });
```

Comment: This code first reads the file with fs.readFile(), then splits the data into lines and each line into key-value pairs. 

Also, you can learn from these resources; 

https://tutorialedge.net/nodejs/reading-writing-files-with-nodejs/
https://www.codingthesmartway.com/how-to-read-and-write-files-with-node-js/
https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/node-js-write-file

Comment: Thank you very much. Reading and writing are working properly. And how to turn to a file for a specific value. For example, I now want to insert siteName in the right place on the site and have him read it from the file. How to do it? How to access a file and pull out just the right field